# Как дождаться ответа от сервера VK?

Tags: swift, xcode, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я выполняю запрос на авторизацию и следом у меня идет проверка ответа:

```
@IBAction func pushButton(_ sender: Any) {
        VKSdk.authorize(self.permission)
        if VKSdk.accessToken() != nil { goToMainVC() }
    }
```

Но на сколько я понял, проверка токена идет сразу после открытия меню авторизации, а не после получения ответа(в связи с чем, условие не выполняется, тк accesToken == nil). Как сделать так, чтобы проверка токена пошла сразу после получения ответа?

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо подписаться на `VKSdkDelegate`.

И реализовать метод

```
func vkSdkAccessAuthorizationFinishedWithResult(result: VKAuthorizationResult)
```

В нем необходимо сделать проверку на удачную авторизацию. Если все хорошо, то проверяйте токен.